# broken queue in jquery image swapping function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am building a site that has a jumbotron with some images changing. I've tried to look answers on the internet, but I couldn't find any. Also, i know that the answer will be something easy, but I can't see it for now.

The problem is that the first image swap goes well, first image fades out and the second fades in. But it breaks down after this. Every next image swap goes like this: current image starts to fade out, but the second one fades in in the same time, meaning that for a moment there are two images displayed at once and whole page beneath them gets pushed down and then up.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 window.setInterval(sliduh1, 3000);

 var slide = $('.activeSlide');

});

function sliduh1() {
  var currentSlide = $('.activeSlide');
  var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

  if (nextSlide.length === 0 ) {
   nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
  }

  currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('activeSlide');
  nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('activeSlide');
}
```

```css
.slider1 img {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 650px;
}
.slide {
 display: none;
}
.activeSlide {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider1">
 <div class="slide activeSlide">
  <img src="imgs/mobile1.png">
 </div>
 <div class="slide">
  <img src="imgs/blueprints1.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="slide">
  <img src="imgs/tools1.png">
 </div>
 <div class="slide">
  <img src="imgs/sourceCode1.png">
 </div>
 <div class="slide">
  <img src="imgs/vr1.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="slide">
  <img src="imgs/market1.png">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you call this function sliduh1(). can you create a fiddle?

Comment: i forgot to show the functions usage in the code. its added now in main post.

Comment: What is expected behaviour? images to fade in/out in same time or to fadein next image only after the active one is faded out? If the former, you would need to set image position to absolute. If the later, you'd need to use complete animation callback: `currentSlide.fadeOut(600,function(){
    $(this).removeClass('activeSlide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('activeSlide');
  }); `

Comment: Just be aware than using a interval for this is bad because you cannot rely on animation duration and interval callback delay. Usually, this is better to use a timeout call recursively once all animations are completed

Comment: expected behabiour is the later, after the first image faded out, next one fades in. im going for a gallery of pictures that is only one picture that gets constantly swapped for another.

Comment: It started to work properly now, thank you very much! but, could i have just one more, quick question? how do i use the recursive function timeout? because that would be exactly what im looking for in terms of slider function's execution

Comment: Please check, This may help you https://jsfiddle.net/zwp9c0um/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A. Wolff answered the question in comments. The answer is using

```
        currentSlide.fadeOut(600, function(){ 
            $(this).removeClass('activeSlide'); 
            nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('activeSlide'); 
        });
```

instead of

```
     currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('activeSlide');
     nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('activeSlide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying this?

```
    function sliduh1() {
        var currentSlide = $('.activeSlide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        if (nextSlide.length === 0 ) {
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
        }

        currentSlide.fadeOut(0).removeClass('activeSlide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('activeSlide');
    }

    window.setInterval(function(){
      sliduh1() ; 
    }, 5000);
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/59hhx02w/2/)

Comment: oh, yes. i did not put it in the post. in main script i use: 
window.setInterval(sliduh1, 3000);

Comment: you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: i used your solution and unfortunately it did not change anything

Comment: it does and it doenst. in fiddle i can see only the 'image' image, so its hard to say. but i introduced your differences into my code and the behaviour did not change

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

Im not very good with html, but wouldnt it work if you set the position to fixed? Otherwise you could try adding another class (ex fadeOutSlide) for the fadeout process. Or set it to fade to another picture instead of one picture fading in and one fading out.